# Elasticsearch match one array with another array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

Let's say I have two indexes `kids` and `outings_for_kids` with the following data

- kids

```
[
  {
    "name": "little kid 1",
    "i_like":["drawing","teddybears"]
  },

]
```

- outings for kids

```
[
  {
    "name": "Teddybear drawing fights with apples!",
    "for_kids_that_like":["apples","teddybears","drawing", "play outside games"]
  },
  {
    "name": "drawing and teddies!",
    "for_kids_that_like":["teddybears","drawing"]
  }
]
```

I want to find an outing that likes the same things little kid 1 likes and a lower score if it has more.

Little kid 1 should not match 100% with the first outing. It has what little kid 1 wants, but but it has more e.g. apples, it should match 50%.
It should match 100% with the second outing.

Comment: When you say match 50% , you mean score should be exactly half? Example top hit should get 100 and rest 50.

Comment: Does below query resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

This will be a 2 step process:

1. Get i_like value from fields index
2. Use i_like from step 1 to query outings index

   1. Use terms query to match each value
   2. Use script to compare array size with number of values
   3. Use constant score to give same score based on index count

Query

```
GET outings/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "for_kids_that_like": {
                        "value": "teddybears"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "for_kids_that_like": {
                        "value": "drawing"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "script": {
                      "script": "doc['for_kids_that_like.keyword'].size()==2" --> replace 2 with size of elements searched
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "boost": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "for_kids_that_like": {
                        "value": "teddybears"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "for_kids_that_like": {
                        "value": "drawing"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "script": {
                      "script": "doc['for_kids_that_like.keyword'].size()>2"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "boost": 50
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "outings",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "IH7tVHEBbLcSRUWr6wPj",
        "_score" : 100.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Teddybear drawing fights with apples!",
          "for_kids_that_like" : [
            "teddybears",
            "drawing"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "outings",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "IX7zVHEBbLcSRUWrhgM9",
        "_score" : 50.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Teddybear drawing fights with apples!",
          "for_kids_that_like" : [
            "teddybears",
            "drawing",
            "apples"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

If you just want to show exact match documents on top followed by partial matches then you don't need constant score(must query with term search will work). By default exact matches are given higher score